# Is partitioning column required in the clustered index in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing, partitioning, sql-execution-plan

I have a table with these indexes:

```
pk_id_sales PRIMARY KEY (id) -> Clustered unique index
uk_sales_id UNIQUE(sales_id -> Non clustered unique index
uk_sales_date_party_name (sales_date, party_name) -> Non clustered, non unique index
```

I want to partition this table on the column `sales_date`.

1. Should I include `sales_date` into the clustered index to get the benefits of partitioning? Is this an optional one? What should be the factors to be considered to make this decision if it is an optional one?
2. What should be the order of columns in the clustered index If I add `sales_date`? Should it be (`id`, `sales_date`) or (`sales_date`, `id`)? What is the role of order here?
3. Will the order of columns in the index make any performance impact in this case?
4. If we include the partition column in the query, will partition elimination always happen regardless of the indexes we have? (Eg: I already have a unique non-clustered index on the `sales_id` (it doesn't contain sales_date). If I make a query with `sales_id` and `sales_date` in the where clause, will the partition elimination happen?)
5. Please share if there is a comprehensive write-up or video that will help to gain a fair understanding of the above-given concepts.

Any response will be appreciated. I can share more details if required.

I tried the following scenarios on an existing empty table. In both cases, the new records are getting inserted into the respective partitions and partition elimination is happening correctly (Found it based on the actual execution plan in azure data studio)

**SCENARIO 1**

I followed the below-given steps based on a tutorial. I don't know we are performing the 4th step.

1. Drop the existing clustered index on `ID`
2. Create a new non-clustered index on `ID`
3. Create a clustered index on `sales_date`
4. Drop the clustered index on `sales_date'

**SCENARIO 2**

Based on another tutorial, I tried the following.

I followed the below-given steps based on a tutorial. I don't know we are performing the 4th step.

1. Drop the existing clustered index on `ID`
2. Create a new non-clustered index on `ID`
3. Create a clustered index on `sales_date`

Comment: Your question includes many questions and is too broad to answer here completely. I suggest you ask separate questions for those, focusing on a specific query and scenario. Key order matters but it depends on your queries.

Comment: @DanGuzman It will be helpful if you can comment on the below-given question only.
The existing clustered index on my table is `id` (It is IDentical and auto incremented). 
I want to partition the table based on `sales_date`. 
My understanding is that we need to add `sales_date` to the clustered index. 
In the examples I saw on web, they are adding it as a second part of the clustered index, ie,
(id, sales_date). 
But for me, it looks like (`sales_date`,`id`) will be more helpful as `id` is unique and it will not help to improve performance. 
Would you be able to comment on this?

Comment: It depends on your queries. The partitioning column must be specified to eliminate parttions and the leftmost key column must be specified to perform an index seek. With unique clustered index key `(id,sales_date)` and no other indexes: 
1) `WHERE id = 1` will perform a seek against every partition to find the single row, 
2) `WHERE sales_date = '20221114'` will full scan the single partition containing the date and return only rows matching date the date, 
3) `WHERE id = 1 AND sales_date = '20221114'` will seek against only the single partiion and touch the single row.

Comment: With unique clustered index key `(sales_date,id)`: 
1) `WHERE id = 1` will full scan every partition to find the single row,
2) `WHERE sales_date = '20221114'` will seek only the single partition containing the date and touch only rows that qualify,
3) `WHERE id = 1 AND sales_date = '20221114'` will seek only the single partition containing the date and touch the single row.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks very much. It is really helpful. This was the answer I was looking for. Thanks again

Comment: @DanGuzmanJust 1 more query. After partitioning an existing table by adding the partition column to the clustered index, do we want to recreate all the non-clustered indexes to realign them?

Comment: If you want the table and indexes aligned, you'll need to recreate the non-clustered indexes. Note you'll need to add sales_date to the unique index key per my answer.

Comment: @DanGuzman Any idea regarding the pros and cons of having tables and indexes aligned?
What does the concept of the aligned index mean?

Comment: Alignment is a requirement to use partition level truncate and switch, as is common with a sliding window. Non-aligned indexes are needed when you need a unique key without the partitioning column, in which partition elimination is also not factor since there's a single be-tree for the non-partitioned index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, the partitioning column is required to be specified explicitly as a key column for all unique indexes. Furthermore, SQL Server will automatically add the partitioning column to [clustered index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver16#partitioning-clustered-indexes) keys if not already specified.

The partitioning column is automatically added as an included column in non-unique non-clustered indexes when not already a key or included column.

**EDIT:**

For this question asked in comment:

> The existing clustered index on my table is id (It is IDentical and
> auto incremented). I want to partition the table based on sales_date.
> My understanding is that we need to add sales_date to the clustered
> index. In the examples I saw on web, they are adding it as a second
> part of the clustered index, ie, (id, sales_date). But for me, it
> looks like (sales_date,id) will be more helpful as id is unique and
> it will not help to improve performance.

It depends on your queries. The partitioning column must be specified to eliminate parttions and the leftmost key column must be specified to perform an index seek.

With unique clustered index key (id,sales_date) and no other indexes:

- `WHERE id = 1` will perform an index seek against every partition to
  find the single row.
- `WHERE sales_date = '20221114'` will perform a full scan of single
  partition containing the date and return only rows matching the date.
- `WHERE id = 1 AND sales_date = '20221114'` will perform a seek
  against only the single partition containing the date and touch the
  single row.

With unique clustered index key (sales_date,id):

- `WHERE id = 1` will full scan every partition to find the single
  row.
- `WHERE sales_date = '20221114'` will perform an index seek on only
  the partition containing the date and touch only rows that qualify.
- `WHERE id = 1 AND sales_date = '20221114'` will perform and index
  seek only the partition containing the date and touch only the single
  row.

Comment: Look at the comment section of the question above for detailed explanation

Comment: @Azru, I added that to my answer for visibility.